# Proving a particular true fact about measure theory and integration.

Tags: measure-theory

[image]

So the above is the problem and my idea of how to approach it. This problem comes from the section on the Countable Additivity of Integration and the Continuity of Integration, but I was not sure how to incorporate those into the prove, if you even need them for the result.

I had no idea what to do after Case 1, leading me to believe that that approach is wrong.

I tried coming up with specific examples to illustrate the idea that this problem is getting at. Let $f(x) = x^2$ and $E = \mathbf{R}$. Is this saying that if I am given $\epsilon = 0.5$, I can pick an $n$ such that when we integrate over $E_n$, the absolute value is less than $0.5$? Or am I getting this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's saying that if $\int_E |f| < \infty$, then $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{E_n}f = 0$. My method to prove this would be to use the dominated convergence theorem on $f \mathbb{1}_{E_n}$.

The main point of this exercise is that if the integral over $\mathbb{R}$ is finite (which can be determined using the MCT), you can calculate it by working out the integral over $[-n,n]$ in the traditional sense (FTC et cetera) and taking limits, because of the result that says the Lebesgue integral over an interval agrees with the Riemann one when it exists.

Your example isn't true as the integral of $x^2$ is not finite, the integral over $E_n$ would always be infinity. It would however be true if $E$ was $[-1,1]$; for $n>1$ the integral over $E_n$ would be zero. A less "obvious" example would be with $E=[0,\infty)$, and $f(x) = e^{-x}$ - in this case the integral over $E_n$ is $e^{-n}$.